# plotly line plots: make one of them bold

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have multiple lines in my plot and I want one of them to stick out. So I am thinking of making it bold. Example in the code below, how can I make one line bolder?

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
fig = plot_ly(economics_long)
fig = fig %>% add_trace(x = ~date, y = ~ value01, color = ~variable, mode = 'lines')
fig
```